# Get only the file names using listFiles in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there an idiomatic Scala solution to obtain only the file *names* from `File.listFiles`?

Perhaps something like:

```
val names = new File(dir).listFiles.somemagicTrait(_getName)
```

and have `names` become a `List[String]`?

I know I can just loop and add them to a mutable list.

Comment: Why don't you want to call `list` instead of `listFiles`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm always wary of answering the wrong part of the question, but as Jean-Phillipe commented, you can get an array of the names from

```
new File(dir).list
```

and if you *really* need a list call `toList` on that.

Answer (score 10):

how about?

```
new File(dir).listFiles.map(_.getName).toList
```